# Trouble with a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to pull in data from several tables, one of which has a one-to-many relationship.  My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  VU.*, 
  UI.UserImg, 
  COALESCE(CI.Interests, 0) as NumInterests 
FROM [vw_tmpUsers] VU 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    [tmpUserPhotos].UserID, 
    CASE WHEN MAX([tmpUserPhotos].uFileName) = NULL 
    THEN 'dflt.jpg'
    ELSE Max([tmpUserPhotos].uFileName) 
     END as UserImg 
  FROM [tmpUserPhotos] 
  GROUP BY UserID) UI 
ON VU.UserID = UI.UserID
```

I've excluded a bunch of LEFT JOINS which follows this, because they're all working properly.

My trouble is, I only want to pull in *one* image name from the table which has a one-to-many relationship.  In order to do this, I've used the MAX function.

My desired result would look like this:

```
UserID  UserName    UserState   UserZip UserIncome  UserHeight  UserImg
1       Jimbo       NY          10012   2           64          1[Blue hills.jpg
2       Jack        MA          06902   3           66          dflt.jpg
3       Lisa        CT          06820   4           64          dflt.jpg
4       Mary        CT          06791   6           67          4[Natalie.jpg
5       Wanda       CT          06791   6           67          dflt.jpg
```

but instead it looks like this:

```
UserID  UserName    UserState   UserZip UserIncome  UserHeight  UserImg
1       Jimbo       NY          10012   2           64          1[Blue hills.jpg
2       Jack        MA          06902   3           66          NULL
3       Lisa        CT          06820   4           64          NULL
4       Mary        CT          06791   6           67          4[Natalie.jpg
5       Wanda       CT          06791   6           67          NULL
```

It's got to be something wonky in my CASE statement, but I'm not very good with them.  I've tried using IS NULL, = NULL, ='NULL', all to no avail.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?  One little tidbit that might shed light; MAX(tmpUserPhotos.uFileName) will only return NULL if there is no matching record in tmpUserPhotos.

Comment: I'd try and move the left join sub-query's case to top-level select list.

Comment: Note, that's a case expression, not a case statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for `NULL` in the outer query:

```
SELECT VU.*, 
       COALESCE(UI.UserImg, 'dflt.jpg') as UserImg,
       COALESCE(CI.Interests, 0) as NumInterests 
FROM [vw_tmpUsers] VU LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT [tmpUserPhotos].UserID, MAX([tmpUserPhotos].uFileName) as UserImg 
      FROM [tmpUserPhotos] 
      GROUP BY UserID
     ) UI 
     ON VU.UserID = UI.UserID ;
```

You are getting `NULL` values because the `LEFT JOIN` has no matches.  No matches means that the `SELECT` is not being executed on any data.

I'll also note that if you have a preference for the priority of the images, then `OUTER APPLY` is easier than `LEFT JOIN`.  However, that would be another question.

Comment: I like this answer because it's clean, but do you have any insight on how well it holds up against the other answers if my dataset grows in excess of 100M records?  Is there any drag on doing a Coalesce versus the IsNull and CASE-based answers above?

Comment: @JohnnyBones . . . I'm not sure what you mean by "hold up".  The processing is driven by the joins and group by and no other answers eliminate that.  It is quite possible that `OUTER APPLY` would have better performance but you would need to test that on your data in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the case statement,  try the 'isnull' function...

```
isnull(MAX([tmpUserPhotos].uFileName),'dflt.jpg') as UserImg
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the using of `TOP` operator and `subquery`.

```
SELECT 
  VU.*, 
  ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 UP.uFileName FROM tmpUserPhotos AS UP
          WHERE UP.userid = VU.userID), 'dflt.jpg') AS userImg
FROM [vw_tmpUsers] VU
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `CASE` expression is returning nulls even though you have included a check for them is that the expression `WHEN MAX([tmpUserPhotos].uFileName) = NULL` will never *evaluate* as true, even when `MAX([tmpUserPhotos].uFileName)` **is** null.

This is because nulls are a special type of value in SQL, one which means "value is not known" - almost any comparison with a null value evaluates as null, not true or false.

For this reason, you need to use a function such as `coalesce` or `isnull` to check whether the expression evaluates as null; alternately, you could amend your case condition to test whether the expression `is null`, like so:

```
CASE WHEN MAX([tmpUserPhotos].uFileName) IS NULL 
    THEN 'dflt.jpg'
    ELSE Max([tmpUserPhotos].uFileName) 
 END as UserImg
```